# Replace a value in a string that is part of a comma-separated list. PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I am trying to replace a name that is part of a comma-separated list.

However, cannot figure out how to do it to match the exact name case insensitive and not catch if is not the exact match

Here is what I got so far.

```
$search  = "My name is Christina and this is another example";
$AllNames = "Lola,Chris,Monic";
$search = str_ireplace(array_map("trim", explode(",", strtolower($AllNames))), '****', $search);
```

So in this case The name of Christina will be marked as ****, although I am looking for Chris only.
Any idea how I can achieve that.

I found some examples on how to do it if I explode the comma-separated list into an array and then foreach trough each item, but perhaps there is an easier solution.

Comment: but your code works fine check it https://phpize.online/?phpses=1528d8142f2f0c9b8cce0fae37f418cc&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql80

Comment: Nope, it gives again "My name is ****tina and this is another example", just checked your link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `\b` word boundary in the values along with `/i` insensitive modifiers with `preg_replace`:

```
$search  = "My name is Christina and this is another example, my friends are Lola and Monica and Monic and Chris. As lowercase: lola, christina, monic, monica, chris.";
$AllNames = ["/Lola/i", "/Chris\b/i", "/Monic\b/i"];
$search = preg_replace($AllNames, '****', $search);
echo $search;
```

Output:

```
My name is Christina and this is another example, my friends are **** and Monica and **** and ****. As lowercase: ****, christina, ****, monica, ****.
```

Note that I did not use the word boundary with `Lola`, but that can be easily added, if needed.